# My django code is requesting a table that doesn't exist

Tags: python, django, database

[image]

[image]

I tried to delete the 'db.sqlite3' file and do the migration again, but it didn't work

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, not as pictures of text.  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: If you are running the django development server with `python manage.py runserver`, the stacktrace will show in the terminal where it is running. You can copy/paste it from there rather than the web page.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you made changes to your model, you need to run `python manage.py makemigrations`. If this is a new project that you have never deployed to production, you can delete the `migrations` folder before running this command.

Then run `python manage.py migrate`.